# Computer crash, when i use recursion to check all html links and sublinks of web

Tags: java, html, recursion, web, crash

i'm tasked to iterate over all links+sublinks of the given web portal.
In most cases , when the web pages are not too complex and big i dont have any problems. The problem starts when i check links of a really complex  site such as tutorialspoint and my computer just crash. I can't find any performance issue in code i attached, so can someone experienced tell me where in my code is a possible threat, where my computer crashes?

uniqueLinks collection is a HashSet for best perfomance for using contains.

```
private void recursiveLinkSearch(String webPage) {
        /** ignore pdf**/
        try {
            logger.info(webPage);
            uniqueLinks.add(webPage);
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(webPage).get();
            doc.select("a").forEach(record->{
                String url=record.absUrl("href");
                if(!uniqueLinks.contains(url)) {
                    /** this would not allow me to to recursively acces to link from other domain **/
                    if(url.contains(getWebPortalDomain())) {
                        recursiveLinkSearch(url);
                    }
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you **don't** literally mean that your computer crashes.  I think you actually mean that your application crashes, and I expect that it is due to a `StackOverflowError`.

There is a fundamental limitation with recursion in Java.  If a thread recurses too deeply, it will fill its stack, and the you get a `StackOverflowError`.  You can work around this (in some cases) by using a larger thread stack, but that only works to a certain point.

In this case, what you should do is to turn your recursive problem into an iterative one.  For example:

1. Use a data structure to hold a queue of URLs waiting to be processed.
2. When you process a page and find links to other pages that need to be processed, add the links to the queue.

The simple way to do this is with an ExecutorService with a bounded worker pool.  That takes care of the queue management as well.

Comment: Hi thanks in advance. At first when i run this code in intellij idea after 5 mins really my pc crashes down, if i run it as generated jar file, then there are not any problems and honestly i do not kniw why it crashes my pc in Idea. I'll try to refactor my recursion to iteration and i would see if it crash.

Comment: I wouldn't run a *hungry* application in an IDE.  What precisely do you mean by "my pc crash down"?  A Windows "blue screen of death"?  A Linux kernel panic?  Did the UI become unresponsive?  Could you move the cursor?  Was the disk drive active?

Comment: Well this is only server side application which now accepts cmd arguments, so i don´t have any UI. i'll get "blue screen of death" . But this only occurs when i run it in Idea, when i run generated jar file from cmd i have no troubles.

Comment: If it is a BSOD, then it is unlikely to be your code's fault (unless you are using native code ... and even then it is unlikely).  The most likely explanation is a hardware issue; e.g. running your application within in the IDE is causing overheating.  But my recommendation is 1) Google for the symptoms (intellij + bsod), and 2) use your workaround.